# Optimizations of nested if and switch statements using callgrind or assembly modifications

Tags: c, optimization, valgrind, callgrind

Consider this piece of code

```
| 34 static bool                                                                     
| 35 _valid_character(char *str, size_t *idx)                                        
| 36 {                                                                               
| 37   char c = str[*idx];                                                           
| 38                                                                                 
| 39   if (c != '\\' && c != '"') {                                                  
| 40     (*idx) += 1;                                                                
| 41     return true;                                                                
| 42   } else if (c == '"') {                                                        
| 43     return false;                                                               
| 44   } else {                                                                      
| 45     char b = str[(*idx) + 1];                                                   
| 46     switch (b) {                                                                
| 47       case '"':                                                                 
| 48       case '\\':                                                                
| 49       case '/':                                                                 
| 50       case 'b':                                                                 
| 51       case 'f':                                                                 
| 52       case 'n':                                                                 
| 53       case 'r':                                                                 
| 54       case 't':                                                                 
| 55         (*idx) += 2;                                                            
| 56         return true;                                                            
| 57       default:                                                                  
| 58         pprint_error("%s@%s:%d invalid escape sequnce \\%c%c (aborting)",       
| 59             __FILE_NAME__, __func__, __LINE__, c, b);                           
| 60         abort();                                                                
| 61     }                                                                           
| 62   }                                                                             
| 63 }
```

This one function is the root cause of a meaning full slowdown in my code. I have tried only using if statements and only using switch statements but this is the best optimization that I can come up with where callgrind results in the best performance. This function accounts for about 25% of the runtime so by the questionable (sorry) 80/20 rule its in my best interest to make this code faster.

Below is the callgrind output visualized with kcachegrind on this function.

[image]

It seems callgrind is saying that my first jump is the worst jump but I have tried all combinations of this if statement to try to minimize jumping and every time the first jump
is the worst jump.

This code was compiled with clang

```
clang ... -Weverything -Werror -Wpedantic -m64 -O0 -g
```

So my question is what is the best way to go about optimizing this code and alternative techniques including assembly modification to optimize this simple yet deadly piece of code.

I would like to keep using `-O0` since I find it the most useful for debugging and finding optimizations. `-O1,2,3,fast` tend to abstract to much away to get a good understanding of what is happening.

-- Edit 1
It was asked for an example input.

```
char cstr[BUF] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\"randomgarbageafterthis";
size_t idx = 0;
while (_valid_character(cstr, &idx));
```

In the end the input is just a string and a loop is called until the end `"` character. The ending idx value holds `cstr[idx] == '"''` to be true.

Comment: Would you give us please a complete example with example inputs and your types? (So we can reproduce your performance and all have the same set of input)

Comment: @JCWasmx86 an example usage of this was appended to the question.

Comment: I'm afraid, this is quite too few of data for a benchmark, one string isn't that much. Furthermore, you should do benchmarks always with the highest optimization level, as `-O0` doesn't mirror the performance, as there are loads and stores for every line.

Comment: Asking for good performance and using `-O0` is merely exclusive and does not make much sense. This mode basically compiles as specified for the abstract machine. You don't give the compiler a chance to show their potential.

Comment: Instead of checking if every character is valid, why not search for the first (possible) invalid character?

Comment: You possibly should add code for the `\377` and `\0xFF` escapes, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to optimize your code, use pen and paper and create a boolean logic table and optimize its algebra with your own mind. After that recreate your code and please use `break;` within your `switch` statements.

For example:

This is your code.

```
if (c != '\\' && c != '"')
{
    (*idx) += 1;
    return true;
}
```

This one is faster than the above one.

```
if (c != '\\')
{
    if (c != '"')
    {
        (*idx) += 1;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Instead of comparing to some chars like `if (c != '\\')` use registered CONSTANTS.

```
register const char BACKSLASH = '\\';
```

And also do:

```
register char c = str[*idx];
```

Constants and variables which are loaded in CPU register are way faster in comparing.

```
if (c != BACKSLASH)
```

Generally, if you want fast code, only use `if` and `else` and use simple boolean compare arguments.

EDIT:

*Code sample 1:*

```
if (c != '\\')
{
    if (c == '"')
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        (*idx) += 1;
        return true;
    }
}
```

is equivalent to:

*Code sample 2:*

```
if (c != '\\')
{
    if (c != '"')
    {
        (*idx) += 1;
        return true;
    }
}
else if (c == '"')
{
    return false;
}
```

But the first code example only compares 2 times, but the second code compares 3 times.

Comment: Could you explain why these changes should improve performance? Given that C uses short circuit evaluation for conditions, there should not be a measurable difference.

Comment: What do you mean with "use break"? Should they use `break` instead of `return` or should only single value cases be used and the instruction copied to each single case?

Comment: Short circuit evaluation only works for simple arguments. Here an example were compiler short circuit evaluation doesn't work: `if (0 && i++){}`. Yes the instruction should be copied for every case in combination with `break;`, otherwise the `switch` statement compares every case, even if it's already true.

Comment: How does it not work? It works perfectly fine. `i++` will never be executed exactly same as with `if(0){if(i++){}}`

Comment: Do you have any reference that `switch` would compare any case values after a matching is found?

Comment: i++ will be executed, even if the first && argument is already false. That's why the short circuit evaluation doesn't work for every case, that's why I'm suggesting the coding way above. I'm sorry, I was wrong with switch, I've mistaken the all case execution with an all compare. Switch compares only as long as its not true. In my opinion using breaks; with switch is a cleaner way to program, especially if you want to program hard and fast boolean algebra.

Comment: If the first part of the expression is already `false`, the part after `&&` will not be evaluated because the result can never get `true` any more. That is what short circuit evaluation does.

Comment: You are right, I tested it, this is curios, because that means:
`int i = 0; int j = 0;` -> `if (0 && i++)` != `if (j++ && 0)`

Comment: Correct. That is the main purpose of short circuit evaluation.